# Android, как создать список, похожий на телефонную книгу

Tags: android, listview, customview

Теперь подробнее, к примеру, на моем устройстве телефонная книга разделена на секции по алфавиту, и сбоку в столбик расположены буквы, почти весь алфавит, они скролятся, и вместе с ними скролится список, можно нажать на букву и список автоматически переместится к записям, которые начинаются с этой буквы. Может уже есть, подобное решение? Так как в IOS, это стандартные модуль, или подскажите как реализовать?

Comment: https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/ListviewFilter

Comment: @metalurgus все таки вам имеет смысл оформлять ответы в виде ответа, а не комментария

Comment: @Barmaley, ИМХО это не достойно ответа. Да и вопрос из разряда "найди мне бибилотеку"

Comment: @metalurgus вы все равно неправы. Почти все можно найти поиском, но "ответы" нужны для того, чтобы был проверенный/правильный/квалицифированный ответ. Ответ может понадобиться и через год и через два, а к тому времени ссылка может уже умереть.